# How to filter with on column1 OR column2 in Quality Center?

Tags: quality-center

Quality Center allows filtering in the defects view.

Is it possible to filter on column1 = "value1" OR column2 = "value2", showing the union of the two filters?

Answer (score 3):

As I know there is no possibility with the built-in GUI filter function as all filter conditions are combined with AND. But you can help yourself with Excel reports and writing your own SQL statements. This is very helpful, especially if you like to do something more sophisticated like metrics.

A very minimalistic example would be following. It selects all tests, which are **either** 'ready' **OR** the responsible user is 'pfarrhor':

```
SELECT TS_NAME
     , TS_STATUS
     , TS_RESPONSIBLE
  FROM TEST
 WHERE TS_STATUS = 'Ready'
    OR TS_RESPONSIBLE = 'pfarrhor'
```

Details about the DB-tables and -fields you will find in the "Database Reference", which is linked on the page "Help / Documentation Library".

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

I tried in the below way.

I logged into the defects module of XYZ project.

Made sure the below options are checked in the view tab.

Grid Filters
Indicator Columns
Favorite Bar

Carried the below steps

Click on Filter/Sort -> Set Filter/Sort

All the fields in the defect module are shown in the Filter condition tab

Each field has a filter condition.

I selected column1 with condition(value) 60.
I selected column2 with condition(value) passed.

This returned only rows having column1 field as 60 and column2 field as passed.

Hope this helps.

Please feel free to extend discussion if not clear I will be happy to assist.

Thanks,
Srihari

Comment: If I understand correctly, this explains how to filter on column1 AND column2. If so, it does not answer the question, which is about column1 OR column2.